# Radon-Nikodym derivative with function composition

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, change-of-variable

Suppose I've got a probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr F, P)$ and a random variable $X: (\Omega, \mathscr F) \to (\mathbb R, \mathbb B)$ where $\mathbb B$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Let $\mu$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure on $(\mathbb R, \mathbb B)$ such that $\mu \gg P_X$ where $P_X = P \circ X^{-1}$ so that the Radon-Nikodym derivate $\frac{dP_X}{d\mu}$ exists. Now let $g : (\mathbb R, \mathbb B) \to (\mathbb R, \mathbb B)$ be an invertible function such that $\mu \gg P_X \circ g^{-1}$ as well.

My question:

> If we know $\frac{dP_X}{d\mu}$, can we say anything about $\frac{dP_X \circ g^{-1}}{d\mu}$?

For convenience, let $P_g = P_X \circ g^{-1}$, $f_X = \frac{dP_X}{d\mu}$, and $f_g = \frac{dP_g}{d\mu}$.

I've been trying to explore this with a change of variables and the definition of the RND (Radon-Nikodym derivative) as
$$
\lambda(A) = \int_A \frac{d\lambda}{d\nu} d\nu
$$
but so far I've had no success and at this point I'm quite stumped.

Comment: In case, $ \mu$ is the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ and $ g \in C^{ 1} ( \mathbb{R})  $,
  you have by Transformation
  \begin{align*}
    \mathbb{P} \left\{ g ( X) \in B \right\} 
    & = 
    \mathbb{P} \left\{ X \in g^{-1} ( B) \right\} 
    = 
    \int_{g^{-1} ( B) }^{} 
    \frac{ d \mathbb{P}_{ X}}{ d \lambda }
    \, d \lambda 
    = \int_{B}^{ } 
    \frac{ d \mathbb{P}_{ Y}}{ d \lambda} ( g^{-1}) 
    \cdot 
    | \det D g^{-1}| 
    \, d \lambda
  \end{align*}
  for $ B \in \mathscr{B}_{ \mathbb{R}}$.